# plot() and dev.off() error message for forestplot()

Tags: r

I've made a figure using forestplot() and I've tried to output it as a high resolution figure but it's not working. The figure plots fine in the R studio plots window, but when I try to use plot() and dev.off() I get an error message.

No idea why.

Thanks for any help!

```
setwd("C:/Users/User/Desktop")
ppi <- 300
png("plotfp.png", width=9*ppi, height=9*ppi, res=ppi)
plot(plotfp)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
> dev.off()
```

Comment: Your code says `plot(plotfp)`  but you do not show us anything about `plotpf`.  What is it?  At least show us `str(plotpf)`.

Comment: It's better if you always [ask with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)